# Always keep focus to last message in a chat screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat

I am working on an a chat application. I am facing a problem in keeping focus on the last message of the chat, in the case when user clicks on the edit text field and the keyboard pops up. What is happening now is, whenever the keyboard pops up, I have to scroll down the chat screen to see the last message. Ideally, I should see the last message in focus without scrolling, no matter if the keyboard is popped up or not.
As per screenshots, screenshot 1 is the actual chat screen where 'Hi' is the last message. In the second screenshot, when I press on edit text to launch keyboard, then 's' shows as the last message and I have to scroll down to see the last message. Actually 'Hi' should show as the last message. Does anyone has a fix for this?  I have used windowssoftinput mode as 'adjustResize' but that's not working

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your layout file

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linear layout manager with recyclerview you can set `recyclerView.setStackFromEnd(true)`. It will set the view to show the last element, the layout direction will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for this...it worked for me...

```
mRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
        {
            if (mRecyclerView != null)
            {
                if (bottom < oldBottom)
                { 
                    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```